# Classifying new documents after cross_val_predict

Tags: python, twitter, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a sample of approximately 10,000 tweets that I want to classify into the categories "relevant" and "not relevant". I am using Python's scikit-learn for this model. I manually coded 1,000 tweets as "relevant" or "not relevant". Then, I ran a SVM model using 80% of the manually coded data as training data and the rest as test data. I obtained good results (prediction accuracy ~0.90), but to avoid overfitting I decided to use cross-validation on all 1,000 manually coded tweets.

Below is my code after already obtaining the tf-idf matrix for the tweets in my sample. "target" is an array listing whether the tweet was marked as "relevant" or "not relevant".

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

clf = SGDClassifier()
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_tfidf, target, cv=10)
predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, X_tfidf, target, cv=10)
```

With this code, I was able to get predictions of what classes the 1,000 tweets belonged to, and I could compare that against my manual coding.

I'm stuck on what to do next in order to use my model to classify the other ~9,000 tweets that I did not manually code. I was thinking to use `cross_val_predict` again, but I'm not sure what to put in the third argument since the class is what I'm trying to predict.

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cross_val_predict is **not** method to actually obtain predictions from the model. Cross validation is a technique for model selection/evaluation, no to **train** model. cross_val_predict is very specific function (which gives you predictions of many models, trained during cross validation procedure). For actual model building yu are supposed to use **fit** to train your model and **predict** to get predictions. No cross validation involved here - as said before - this is for model selection (to choose your classifier, hyperparamters etc.) and not to train actual model.

Comment: Thanks, @lejlot! I'm still a bit confused regarding cross_val_predict. What is it returning exactly? Also, let's say I ran `cross_val_predict` and `cross_val_score` for a SVM and a naive Bayes classifier. Am I supposed to use the output of those functions to, let's say, decide between the classifiers?

Comment: cross_val_predict internally trains as many models as many splits your provide(10 in your case), each on different splitting of data. After that it uses each model to predict the unseen data, and concatenates all the results to create the list of predictions. This is mostly *debugging*/*analysis* tool, not something to use for training. For your use case you **should not** use cross_val_predict at all. You can use cross_val_score to decide between models (like SVM or NB) though.

Comment: That makes sense thanks @lejlot!! How then do you prevent overfitting for text classification models?

Comment: cross validation does not 'prevent overfitting', choice of a model based on cross validation is supposed to help (since the cv score is an estimate of generalization error).

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks for all the help, @lejlot :)